# how can i transform Object3D Coordinates with values based on world position Coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

hello i have a spinning parent object containing a bunch of child objects. theese child objects are programmed to move on based on the cursor. however the x and y coordinates are completely relative to the spinning parent object. so whenever i want the child to move left-"-x relative to the world coordinates" it moves "-x relative to its parents coordinates"
 [image of what i have and want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA2qZ.png)

i dont believe deataching the child from the parent will do in my situation... 
i think the best approach is if its possible to calculate the direction i want from the objects local coordinates, but i dont really know hence im asking

[picture of actual object / "chieldren"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Wcz.png)

Comment: That looks super cool :o Any chance we can see it live? Can you use child.translateX()? I found that function works on the worldposition of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

- Detach the child from its parent with `scene.attach( child );`
- Perform the transformation in world space
- Attach the object back to its parent via `parent.attach( child );`

The important bit here is the usage of [Object3D.attach()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.attach).

`three.js R114`

Comment: well thx for the answer... it does indeed work, the problem is all the children are meant to return to their exact start position and messing with the array ruins this...

Comment: What do you mean with "messing with the array"? Any chances to demonstrate what you do with an editable live example?

Comment: hello i feel bad for not beeing able to answer earlier. i truely appreciate the help though... i had to drop this feature because of the assignments time limit and i wont waiste anymore of your time. in short though the chieldrens startposition got saved in an array but when deataching and reataching them, thier hierarki wouldnt match the arrays indexes anymore. anyway i guess this can be solved by some more thought through array sorting. sorry for waisting your time.